# Fixing hub gasket squeal

Tags: wheels, repair, hub

I have a relatively new Salsa Journeyman, which has now, after about 200km, developed a squeal in the front hub.
The squeal is relatively quiet on low speeds, but gets noticeably loud when riding faster.
The wheel is fitted with an unmarked Formula hub, which i believe is a DC-20 model based on its shape.
I did already check the brakes and it's definitly not caused by them.
It looks like the gasket part of the hub is rotating with the wheel and causing the squeal.

[image: Gasket part of the hub]

How do I fix this squealing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At 200km you should be able to take the bike to where you bought it for a free tune-up to adjust brakes and derailleur indexing etc.

Ask to have the front hub looked at as it definitely should not be making noise and will be covered under the warrantee. The problem might be fixed by lubricating the area around the rubber gasket, but you want to make sure there is not a problem with the bearings.